# HTML: can not align table cells

Tags: html, css

I generate automatic emails about TFS build. I need to make a table, therefore I create HTML Table to assign it to property Body of instance of object `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`:

```
 msg.Body = message + table;
```

My C# code works fine, however I can not to align my HTML table. This is part of generated HTML:

```
<table border="1" style="border: 1px solid; ">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <b>Requirement #1172660: </b>
        <br/>Malicious apps weren't recognized on desktop (webroot did not respond) <br/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <b>Changeset #444273:</b>
        <br/>By John Smith: increase webroot external service timeout 11/05/2016 10:38:59<br/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <b>Changeset #455754:</b>
        <br/>By John Smith: Added retry mechanism to external service call 12/07/2016 18:19:23<br/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <b>Changeset #455969:</b>
        <br/>By John Smith: Increased webroot timeout to 30 sec 13/07/2016 15:10:42<br/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <b>Changeset #458813:</b>
        <br/>By John Smith: Fixed bug in soapfull request retry 28/07/2016 12:16:16<br/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="5">
        <b>Requirement #1172660: </b>
        <br/>Malicious apps weren't recognized on desktop (webroot did not respond) <br/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <b>Changeset #444273:</b>
        <br/>By John Smith: increase webroot external service timeout 11/05/2016 10:38:59<br/>
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <b>Changeset #455754:</b>
      <br/>By John Smith: Added retry mechanism to external service call 12/07/2016 18:19:23<br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <b>Changeset #455969:</b>
      <br/>By John Smith: Increased webroot timeout to 30 sec 13/07/2016 15:10:42<br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <b>Changeset #458813:</b>
      <br/>By John Smith: Fixed bug in soapfull request retry 28/07/2016 12:16:16<br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">
      <b>Requirement #1180032: </b>
      <br/>Orange FR - Change text before Factory Reset / Flash <br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top">
      <b>Changeset #455265:</b>
      <br/>By John Smith:  11/07/2016 10:33:46<br/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I past this code to some HTML compilator http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_table_span
I get sutisfactory result:
[image]
Although, as you can see, right cell a little bit aligned to bottom.
Nervertheles, my headache starts when I receive my email. The generated table looks different:
[image]

As you can see, generated table in email has considerable empty space in the top of the right cells. 
I've never dealt with HTML in my life and I don't have a clue how to remove this gap, align it to top or to keep the same look and feel of table like in HTML (the look and feel on first screenshot).
I would be glad to any help or advice.

Comment: You should try to create a valid table architecture : table > tbody > tr > td. Table display in emails are very very stricts. Then to force style, you have to manually add style="".

Comment: tbody - this is the only thing I miss, right?

Comment: You need to inspect the HTML in the email. Grab that code (the method varies from client to client) and paste it in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Yup, I know that this kind of "little" detail has saved my life more than once. As I said, emailing is very capricious. Btw, If you want to fix each table sizes, you have to mention it in each td. Like <td style="width: xx"

Comment: some email clients struggle with `rowspan`. try nested tables instead

Comment: Do we have a way to force a default type of Table for email like in simple HTML?

Comment: Good idea to inspect the email's HTML.

Comment: I found the way!
But thank you for help and advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: I need to change my table structure:

Now I use this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="1">Bug 1</td >
        <td>Changeset 1</td >
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">Bug 1</td >
        <td>Changeset 1</td >
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Changeset 2</td >           
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">Bug 2</td >
        <td >Changeset 1</td >
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Changeset 2</td >           
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td >Changeset 3</td >           
    </tr>
   <tr>
        <td rowspan="4">Bug 2</td >
        <td >Changeset 1</td >
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td >Changeset 2</td >           
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td >Changeset 3</td >           
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td >Changeset 3</td >           
    </tr>
```

Instead of this:

```
<table>
        <tr>
          <td rowspan="3">Bug 1</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Changeset 1</td>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Changeset 2</td>           
        </tr>



        <tr>
            <th rowspan="5">Bug 2</th>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Changeset 1</th>           
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>Changeset 2</th>           
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Changeset 3</th>           
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>Changeset 4</th>           
        </tr>
</table>
```